# save avi files in blender using python script

Tags: python, video, save, blender

I have created an animation using Blender. Does anybody know how I can save .avi file of the rendered animation using a python script.

My second question is that I want to run the animation with different parameters and save the video. Basically, I want to reset the animation and run it again with a new force and save a separate video file. I want to do these automatically instead of manually. Is it possible to do that with scripting?

Comment: There may be more people that can help you on the [Blender Stack Exchange](http://blender.stackexchange.com/) :)

Answer (score 1):

`bpy.context.scene.render.filepath` contains the filename that the render will be saved to, you can change this along with each setting that you want to try out and then use [`bpy.ops.render.render(animation=True)`](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_74_5/bpy.ops.render.html?highlight=render#bpy.ops.render.render) to render the animation.